# Ruby on Rails : how to pass value to javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to pass the value from **<%= controller.controller_name %> <%= controller.action_name %>** to javascript as below

```
return (document.body.className += " load-done 
            '<%= controller.controller_name %>' '<%= controller.action_name %>'
        ");
```

but it doesn't work, can anyone advise on this?

Comment: Is it a `js.erb` file?

Comment: @Deepesh it's the ".js" file

Comment: You can't pass the value on `.js` file. Try to rename the file to `.js.erb` and see if that works for you.

Comment: After renaming and compiling I got this error message "NameError: undefined local variable or method `controller' for ....."
```
 _erbout.<< "      return (document.body.className += \" load-done ".freeze; _erbout.<<(( controller.controller_name ).to_s); _erbout.<< " ".freeze; _erbout.<<(( controller.action_name ).to_s); _erbout.<< "\");\n".freeze
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is lacking information so I just guess you want to pass some data directly from the controller to your JS code. There are two "normal" ways to do this. The first is to do a direct call to the controller as a http call and return the response as a json.
The second method is to pass the data as a class variable, then you can access it in the views folder from the html files. Here you can pass the variable to a div, span or whatever and access it in the JS by finding the html tag in the JS like so:

```
# controllers: 

def some_controller_method
  @temp = 'example data, could be any type'
end

# views
<%= content_tag :div, class: "some_class", data: {temp: @temp} do %>
<% end %>

# JS
$('.some_class').data('temp')
```